# FileNotFound Error...for python and .json

Tags: python

I am trying to make a hypixel API code that will get information and print it out.I just started working on it and am trying to get the simple stuff down but it says there is no such file or directory that i listed

Here is my code

```
#Imports
import requests
import json
from pprint import pprint

#Functions
def get_info(call):
    r = requests.get(call)
    return r.json()



#Variables
API_FILE = open("API_KEY.json","r")
API_KEY = json.loads(API_FILE.read())["API_KEY"]


#Code
print(API_KEY)
```

And the API_KEY.json

```
{
    "API_KEY": "xxx-xxx-xx-xx-xx-x-xx"
    }
```

Then the error message that it tells me

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "d:\Python\Microsoft VS Code\Codes\Projects\MineCraft\skyblock_utils.py", line 12, in <module>
    API_FILE = open("API_KEY.json","r")
FileNotFoundError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory: 'API_KEY.json'
```

Im not sure what i did wrong

Comment: First off never share your API key. Where is the API_KEY.json file relative to the where your code is located?

Comment: i beeped the key out ...and i use visual studio code and it is in the same folder.not sure how to show you it

Comment: "the same folder" as what?  If you don't give a path, files are relative to the "current directory".  That is NOT the same as "the directory containing the script".  You can figure out the directory containing the script from the `__file__` variable, and that's usually a good way to do it.

Comment: can i post a screen shot some how?

Comment: what do you mean by " You can figure out the directory containing the script from the __file__ variable, and that's usually a good way to do it."

Comment: if you `print(__file__)` inside of your code (before the error) you would be able to see the file path of the script (i.e. the file path to the code that you just inserted the __file__ into). In Visual Studio Code you can right click on the API_KEY.json file  name in the explorer tab and get either the relative path or the full path (use the full path for now). If you put that full path into your `open()` statement the file should load